# elastic search, azure data factory

Tags: azure, elasticsearch, azure-data-factory

I have a request to utilize Elasticsearch within Azure for monitoring Azure Data Factory and Synapse SQL Pools. This includes monitoring pipeline failures, triggers, database status, and other relevant metrics.

I thought that to achieve this, you can just start by provisioning Elasticsearch through the Azure Portal and specifying the resource group for monitoring purposes. After setting up Elasticsearch, you'll need to configure it to collect data from Azure Data Factory and Synapse SQL Pools.

I'll need to provide Azure Data Factory endpoints to Elasticsearch so that it can retrieve logs and other monitoring data. Similarly, I'll need to specify Synapse endpoints to Elasticsearch to access the required data.

Is my understanding correct, or there is a need for another tool in between to extract the data from the sources (data factory, synapse, etc) and transform and then send to Elastic?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

> There is a need for another tool in between to extract the data from the sources (data factory, synapse, etc) and transform and then send to Elastic?

***No, there is no need of third-party tool is required to get the logs of azure resources in elastic search.***

As mentioned in this [document](https://www.elastic.co/blog/getting-started-with-the-azure-integration-enhancement)

> **Azure subscription logs provide insight into any subscription-level events. Azure resource logsdescribe the operation of those services or resources.**

While creating **Elastic resource** under **Logs & metrics** tab it provides checkboxes for **subscription activity logs and/or resource logs.**

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/reference/supported-logs/logs-index) are all supported logs are mentioned.